# Python debugger в SublimeText2

Tags: python, отладка, sublime-text

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, интерактивный Python-дебаггер для ST2

Comment: 4 года программирую на Python -  ни разу не понадобился интерактивный дебаггер. Вполне хватает отладочной печати + кастомные обрабочики исключений с печатью локальных переменных. Хотя возможно, это зависит от области применения языка. Возможно при реализации некоторых программ он и будет полезным.

Comment: @dred, не скажите: при отладке больших чужих кодов при отсутствии их автора - очень пригодился бы.

Comment: @eigenein - с тем же успехом отладка больших проектов, написанных другими людьми, делается с помощью отладочной печати. Отладчик, несомненно, полезный инструмент, но его, как и любой инструмент надо применять с умом. Основной недостаток отладчика для меня - он не позволяет увидеть работу системы целиком, а заставляет смотреть только в одну точку программы, часто заваливает деталями, когда нужно обозреть код "с высоты птичьего полета" для его понимания. При анализе лог-файла именно и получаешь именно такой аспект исследуемой системы(или подсистемы).

Comment: http://outofmemoryblog.blogspot.ru/2012/08/python-development-with-sublime-text-2.html

Этот?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону Visual Studio Code.

Он кросплатформенный, работает на разных популярных ОС (как и Sublime).

VS Code имеет поддержку Python с помощью стороннего модуля (Sublime имеет встроенную поддержку).

VS Code поддерживает отладку Python-кода с помощью визуального отладчика (в Sublime отладчик не предусмотрен).